# psql: FATAL: Password authentication failed for user “postgres” WINDOWS

Tags: sql, postgresql

I just installed postgresql 9.0 on my pc.
When it ask for password during install, I entered *password*.

after install I went to command prompt to import a SQL file.
I use the command `psql -f filename.sql`. This prompts me for a password to which I enter *password*.

It then complains that authentication failed for user *Morne Nel*. I dont exist as a user yet.

I then tried `psql -h localhost -U postgres` to which I enter the password *password*.
Only to get this message:
`FATAL: Password authentication failed for user "postgres"`

What Can I do to resolve this madness?

**#** Could it be that Jasper Reports server might have something to do with it, is also installs prostgres does iet not?

Comment: Try the user postgres is running as.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean. I dont understand

Comment: First, why on earth would you install PostgreSQL 9.0? It's an old release. Anyway ... if `psql -h localhost -U postgres` fails, then whatever password you're entering isn't the password you entered in the installer. You can reset the password though: http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/19643/7788

Comment: In the meantime I uninstalled 9.0 and installed 9.3. made 101% sure i entered 'password'. Getting the same issue. Will try this reset though. **UPDATE** Tried the update password method. Still says pass auth failed

Comment: In that case, at a guess you have multiple PostgreSQL versions installed and running on different ports. The one you just installed must be running on a port other than the default port 5432. The installer asks you what port you want to use, but if you don't remember you can find it in `postgresql.conf` in your `data` directory inside the install, or you can try port `5433`, `5434`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So is seems that Jasper Reports Server was the culprit here.
`Jasper` was running on `port 5432` and `Postgres 9.3` was running on `port 5433`

I knew that it was on port 5433 from install, but I just assumed that if you try and run command prompt commands that it would use the correct port.

So after uninstalling Jasper Reports Server and changing the port number for Posgres 9.3 in the config file to 5432, I restarted my PC and it worked.